# Inject Adsense in the nth element of li

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense

I am trying to inject AdSense in the 4th and 7th element of a list item with jQuery but what I have at the moment breaks when I use AdSense but works with ordinary html or text.

Here is what i have

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var couter = 1;
        $( ".page-itemlist li" ).each(function() {

            if(couter==4 || couter==7){
                $(this).before( '<li class="adsense-here"> ADSENSE GOES HERE</li>' );
            }
            couter++;
        });
    });
</script>
```

The above works but when I insert AdSense it breaks, this is what I am trying to achieve :

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var couter = 1;
            $( ".page-itemlist li" ).each(function() {

                if(couter==4 || couter==7){
                    $(this).before( '
                                   <li class="adsense-here">

<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-7615453880179233"
     data-ad-slot="3708363880"
     data-ad-format="auto"
     data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>

                                   </li>'
                   );
                }
                couter++;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-line string is not supported by single quote' in javascript.

You need to use backquote `

```js
                    $(this).before( `
                                   <li class="adsense-here">

<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-7615453880179233"
     data-ad-slot="3708363880"
     data-ad-format="auto"
     data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>

                                   </li>`
                   );
```

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var couter = 1;
            $( ".page-itemlist li" ).each(function() {

                if(couter==4 || couter==7){
                    $(this).before( `
                                   <li class="adsense-here">

<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-7615453880179233"
     data-ad-slot="3708363880"
     data-ad-format="auto"
     data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
<\/script>

                                   </li>`
                   );
                }
                couter++;
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="page-itemlist">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I used backquote and it still doesn't work, can you post an example of what you mean?

Comment: It still doesn't Work

Comment: escape `<\/script>`

Comment: Also instead of adding `<script>` part into the inserted html, add `adsbygoogle.push{});` after each `$(this).before()` call:
`if(couter==4 || couter==7){
  $(this).before('...');
  adsbygoog.push({});
}`